# jquery datepicker set mindate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jQuery datepickers to select a **from** and **to** dates. I have the following code that if you select the 15th June in the first then in the second you now can only select from the 15th onwards.

The issue I have is I really need to set the **to** datepicker to +1 day. So the user could only select 16th onwards.

My skills are not advanced enough to add the date to the parseDate

```
    $(function() {
        var dates = $( "#from_date, #to_date" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat ||
            $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
            selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
    });
    });
```

Comment: I see `minDate: 0,`  could this be changed to fulfill your purposes?

Comment: Yes I already have it working setting the min date, I just need to add the ability to add one day to the above date code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To limit one datepicker based on the other, one can set the `minDate` and `maxDate` settings to the date selected in the other datepicker etc.

Something like this

```
$(function() {

     /* global setting */
    var datepickersOpt = {
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        minDate   : 0
    }

    $("#from_date").datepicker($.extend({
        onSelect: function() {
            var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate()+2); //add two days
            $("#to_date").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minDate);
        }
    },datepickersOpt));

    $("#to_date").datepicker($.extend({
        onSelect: function() {
            var maxDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-2);
            $("#from_date").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", maxDate);
        }
    },datepickersOpt));
});
```