# jQuery datepicker prevent selecting date before arrival date

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck on this piece of code, I'm able to select the arrivalDate and departureDate and display the numbers of days, I can also stop the user selecting a day in the past i.e no date before today.

But where I am stuck is if they select say 11/07/2013 in arrivalDate, how can I stop them selecting a day between the 08/07/2013 or 10/07/2013 etc in departureDate.

I tried putting #arrivalDate as option in datepicker to stop user going back but could not get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated

```
$("#ArrivalDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: 0,
});

$('#DepartDate').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function () {
        var diff = dateDiff($('#ArrivalDate').datepicker("getDate"),
        $('#DepartDate').datepicker("getDate"));
        if (diff == 0) {
            $("#noDays").html("1 day");
        } else if (diff == 1) {
            $("#noDays").html(diff + " day");
        } else {
            $("#noDays").html(diff + " days");
        }
        alert(diff);
    }
});

function dateDiff(startDate, endDate) {
    if (endDate && startDate) return (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    return "Please enter arrival and departure dates!";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery datepicker set mindate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368534/jquery-datepicker-set-mindate)

Comment: Thats quite simple, why dont you just try passing the "departure date" as first parameter and "arrival date " as second parameter to `dateDiff()` function . in this scenario it will return negative value, which will allow you to prevent user from this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of the [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) option in the `DepartDate` onSelect of the `ArrivalDate` datepicker:

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/YtazW/

```
$("#ArrivalDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: 0,

    onSelect: function () {
        $('#DepartDate').datepicker('option', {
            minDate: $(this).datepicker('getDate')
        });
    }
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/YtazW/

Comment: Hi Steve thanks I was so close, I put "option", minDate: $(this).datepicker('getDate') BUT did not use {}, which explains why I did not work,

Comment: Hi adeneo I do not believe my question is a possible duplicate, as I had done most of the code and it turned out with Steve's answer I realised I had missed adding the {} in an earlier attempt at solving this problem.