# With 2 dates I need to block the datepicker option for 2nd date based on 1st date selection

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery

I have two datepicker fromdate and todate. Based on fromdate selection, I need to block the dates above the fromdate in the second datepicker(toDate).

**e.g**

```
 fromdate: 17/6/2013 (MM/DD/YYYY)
 todate: selection should be available from 17/6/2013. any date above 17/6/2013 should be disabled.
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery datepicker set mindate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368534/jquery-datepicker-set-mindate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery UI's datepicker, I think you're looking for Date range. You'd have a markup like this :

```
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" />
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
```

Then, in the JS,

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      //not needed
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      //to show the month dropdown
      changeMonth: true,
      //the number of months to be shown when input is focussed
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      //**Important!**
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        //dynamically set min-date of second datepicker to selected date in the first datepicker 
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        //dynamically set max-date property of #from text box
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

Docs : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range