# How to enable dates that match with the data in rangeselector?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datepicker

I have added a `datepicker` to `highchart` as follows.

```
$(function() {

$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]

    }, function(chart){

        // apply the date pickers
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $(chart.container).parent())
                .datepicker();
        }, 0);
    });
});


// Set the datepicker's date format
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        this.onchange();
        this.onblur();
    }
});
```

});

How can I prevent users select dates that are out of data range? For example, if the oldest data I have is `25-12-2010`, then in the date selector dates before `25-12-2010` should be disabled. Appreciate any help

Comment: Which datepicker do you use, from what library?

Comment: datepicker from Jquery

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ That one? If so, please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set [beforeShowDay](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) callback. You should return true or false if the date is valid - in your case you can check if the date is within the navigator range.

```
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
      var d = new Date(date).getTime();
      var {min, max} = chart.navigator.xAxis;

      return [min <= d && d <= max];
    },
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/m11tbw1c/

Answer (score 0):

read this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16368722/3469614

but you need to:
1. Get the start date from database or file
2. get the end date from database or file