# Set minimum datepicker "form" and "to" in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form made for a date selection:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="id_vehicle">Request for: <?php echo $vehicle->brand?> <?php echo $vehicle->model?></label>
  <input type="hidden" id="id_vehicle" name="id_vehicle" value = "<?php echo $vehicle->id_vehicle?>">
  <br>
  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="date" id="from" name="from">
  <label for="to">to</label>
  <input type="date" id="to" name="to">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 1em;">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col text-center"  value="Request">
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I need to have the `from` date minimum value as the today date and the `to` date >= of the `from` date. I'm trying to do so with datepicker, but I'm a newbie with javascript, so I was wondering if someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368534/jquery-datepicker-set-mindate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery datepicker set mindate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368534/jquery-datepicker-set-mindate)

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be done. hope it helps ( :

```js
//JavaScript:
function setToDate(val){
    document.getElementById("to").setAttribute("min", val);
}

var today = new Date(),
    day = today.getDate(),
    month = today.getMonth()+1, //January is 0
    year = today.getFullYear();
    
    if(day<10){
      day='0'+day
    } 
    if(month<10){
      month='0'+month
    }
    today = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;

    document.getElementById("from").setAttribute("min", today);
    document.getElementById("to").setAttribute("min", today);
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <form>
  <label for="id_vehicle">Request for: <?php echo $vehicle->brand?> <?php echo $vehicle->model?></label>
  <input type="hidden" id="id_vehicle" name="id_vehicle" value = "<?php echo $vehicle->id_vehicle?>">
  <br>
  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="date" id="from" name="from" onchange="setToDate(this.value)">
  <label for="to">to</label>
  <input type="date" id="to" name="to">
  <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 1em;">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col text-center"  value="Request">
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have this problem: if I run the code from the snippet here, everything is fine, but if I run it in my pc I can select a To date that is before the from date... The mininum date for the from date is working fine tho...

Comment: Hey,
On which client you open the page? (which client browser when you run it from the pc)

Comment: I'm using chrome

Comment: Can you post your code here if there is something different in it? because I tested it in chrome and it works. first thing first, just open this page on your pc computer, if it works then you need to figure out what's different